# Can I close a bootstrap modal (v3) and link to a different site, without using JS?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've created a modal (Bootstrap v3) on a site that doesn't allow for any Javascript, just HTML and CSS (Bootstrap v3). I'd like to have a button at the bottom that users can click to close the modal, that will also open up a new page. Currently the button can either only close the modal, or open a new page, not both.

Is there a way to do this in Bootstrap v3, without using JS?

```
<a href="link" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" data-dismiss="modal">I Agree</a>
```

Comment: This should work fine. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @rgedit I think this only works for Bootstrap 4 though. Unfortunately the site I'm building the modal in, uses bootstrap 3, so the modal just closes. And the link doesn't open